# Peer review for edits?

Tags: support, policy, peer-review

```
Thanks for your edit!
This edit will only be visible to you until it is peer reviewed.
```

Edited [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/how-can-i-make-a-weather-proof-bike/2649#2649) (fixed a link), and once I was done I saw the message above. I don't think I've seen that before - is that because I was editing a moderator's answer? Or is there some other guideline to when this comes up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm seeing a new color of "moderator action required" badge at the top, and when I click on it, I get this text:

> These edits were suggested by users who have not yet earned full edit privileges. Approve edits you know are correct; reject those you know are wrong. Leave ambiguous edits for other users to judge.

Followed by a side-by-side comparison of your version and the original version and "Approve" and "Reject" buttons.

Since it looked correct, I approved it, and the change took effect immediately. If I wasn't a moderator (or especially high rep user), it may have taken two users approving it for your edit to take effect.

Another 100 rep points and you won't get that anymore.

This is a new feature that they seem to have rolled out fully to all the stackexchange sites yesterday:

- [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446)
- [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work)

Comment: Ah, that explains it, thanks!

Comment: This is wonderful, and I hope it will let lower-rep users get more involved in the site. Stack Exchange's mission is to *make the internet better*, and improving writing and removing typos will definitely help to do that.